# Luasockets get the lua files

Tags: sockets, lua, luarocks, luasocket

can I get the the .lua files that comes with luasockets somewhere? Like ftp.lua , http.lua etc...

I have no idea how to build something I trying a lot with VStudio but no luck. I tried to look how to build but I didnt understood, did I need lua? luarocks? installed in my pc?

If I had that .lua files it would be ok for my problem

Comment: Luasockets requires both compiled C libs and Lua files. The Lua files alone aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Although it wasn't clearly specified, you're on *Win*. 
Also "*can I get the the .lua files that comes with luasockets*" doesn't make much sense, because if you already have *LuaSocket*, then you have the (required *.lua*) files as well (as they are part of the package).

Anyway, I have built the packages for *Win* and they can be downloaded from **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/LuaSocket](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/LuaSocket)**. The *.zip* archives are self contained (meaning they are ready to run), check the mentions about compatible *Lua* versions (you'll most likely have to download and unpack them on your *PC*, then install *LuaSocket* on top). 
You'll also find there the official repository where I've downloaded the sources from.

Although the real thing happens inside the *.dll* (codewise in the *.c* files), you'll probably find some useful stuff in the *.lua* (wrapper) files as well.